# Deriving the canonical link for a binomial distribution

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model, exponential-family

I define an exponential dispersion family as any distribution whose PMF/PDF is 
$$f(y \mid \boldsymbol\theta) = \exp\left\{\phi[y\theta - b(\theta)] + c(y, \phi) \right\}\text{, } y \in \Omega$$
where $\Omega$ is in the support of a random variable $Y$ in the family.

Suppose $Y_1, \dots, Y_m$ are independent and binomially distributed ($n$ trials, success probability $p_i$). I've already shown that the Binomial distribution satisfies the above, with
$$\begin{align}
\phi &= 1 \\
\theta_i &= \log\left(\dfrac{p_i}{1-p_i} \right) \\
b(\theta_i) &= n\log\left(\dfrac{1}{1-p_i}\right) \\
c(\phi, y_i) &= \log\binom{n}{y_i}\text{.}
\end{align}$$
After some work, I showed that, as a function of $\theta_i$, 
$$b(\theta_i) = n\log(e^{\theta_i} + 1)$$
(this is consistent with what I found at http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/tutorials/xlghtmlnode38.html)
and I understand that 
$$\mu_i = b^{\prime}(\theta_i) = n \cdot \dfrac{e^{\theta_i}}{e^{\theta_i}+1}\text{.}$$

I also understand that what we need to do is solve for $\theta_i$ in the above, and the canonical link function would be $g(\mu_i) = \theta_i$ according to above. But one thing bothers me: when I run the above through [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20mu%20%3D%20n%20*%20exp(theta)%2F(exp(theta)%2B1)%20for%20theta), I obtain
$$g(\mu_i) = \theta_i = \log\left( \dfrac{\mu_i}{n-\mu_i}\right)\text{.}$$
Every source I've seen says that the $n$ above should be a $1$ for the binomial canonical link function. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost right, and it's such an easy fix:

$$\mu_i = p_i n$$ so $$\log(\frac{\mu_i}{n - \mu_i}) = \log(\frac{np_i}{n - np_i}) = ...$$

So, the $n$ can be a 1, *as long as you swap out $\mu_i$ for $p_i$*.

Comment: So if I'm understanding what you're saying correctly, it's this: if I wanted to write the canonical link in terms of $p_i$, it would be the logit, but if I wanted to write it in terms of $\mu_i$, it would be what I have above (and in both cases, they are identical for when $n = 1$ , i.e., the Bernoulli)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you find any sources that mix the $\mu$ and the $1$, they are probably assuming $n=1$.